Why closing the same fd after vfork() doesn't cause error?
I have the following code snippet, which opens a file and tries to grep something in it in child process. Child process is spawned using vfork() + exec().
FILE *file = fopen("filename.txt", "r");

int pipefds[2];
pipe(pipefds);

pid_t pid = vfork();
if (pid == 0) {
  // Child process
  close(pipefds[0]); // child doesn't need read end of the pipe

  dup2(fileno(file), STDIN_FILENO);
  pclose(file);
  
  dup2(pipefds[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
  close(pipefds[1]);
  
  execlp("grep", "grep", "pattern", NULL);
}

if (close(pipefds[1]) == -1) { // Why is this successful
  perror("close");
  return 1;
}
char buffer[1024];

// Why I can read from pipefds[0] if I closed it before exec() function
while (read(pipefds[0], buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1) > 0) {
  std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
}

pclose(file); // Segmentation Fault here, as expected

As, between vfork() and execlp() child and parent processes share the same address space, calling close(pipefds[1]) in child process should also alter fds of parent process. But when I call close(pipefds[1]) after exec() I don't get an error, which I get in the case of pclose(file). Why is this the case?

please don't tag both c and c++ unless you're asking about interop between the two languages

You closed it in a different process, didn't you?

There is almost no safe way to use vfork(), and even if you manage to use it safely, its performance advantage over fork() is insignificant on modern Unixes.  vfork() was obsoleted in POSIX.1-2001, and removed from POSIX.1-2008, 16 years ago. Avoid, avoid, avoid.

And to add to what @JohnBollinger posted, there's no way to rely on the unsafe aspects of vfork() either - vfork() is allowed to use a shared address space with and to pause the parent process while it's running - it doesn't have to.  Neither "vfork() will pause my parent process" nor "If I change this in the vfork()'d process the changes will appear in the parent process" can be relied on.  Offhand, I'm pretty sure fork() itself meets all the requirements of the vfork()'s specified behavior - or at least the ones vfork() had before POSIX eliminated it.

With Linux, the new process created by vfork() shares the same virtual address space as the original, but it gets copies of everything else, including file descriptors. From the manpage:

As with fork(2), the child process created by vfork() inherit copies of various of the caller's process attributes (e.g., file descriptors, signal dispositions, and current working directory); the vfork() call differs only in the treatment of the virtual address space...

However, note this (emphasis added):

(From POSIX.1) The vfork() function has the same effect as fork(2), except that the behavior is undefined if the process created by vfork() either modifies any data other than a variable of type pid_t used to store the return value from vfork(), or returns from the function in which vfork() was called, or calls any other function before successfully calling _exit(2) or one of the exec(3) family of functions.

So your use of close(), dup2(), etc. is invalid. It's best just to avoid use of vfork() entirely; it's just too hard to use safely without stepping off the cliff of undefined behavior (An unsuccessful call to an exec() function probably counts as UB; it modifies errno after all. You can't log errors. You can't do file descriptor redirection, etc.... just stick with fork().)

As a side note, on Linux (and likely every other halfway modern Unix), fork() is not copying anything (from the virtual memory; it still copies filehandles and stuff) unless one of the processes actually writes to it ("copy-on-write"). That way, most of the performance benefit that vfork() is meant to provide evaporates.

Isn't that note just the minimum that POSIX requires? If you don't care about portability to other operating systems, then doesn't Linux, especially with its "never break userspace" guarantee, let you do significantly more than that and have it be well-defined, as long as you're careful?
